# ideas how to send an url of an app to a client (besides email and sms)

Tags: javascript, url, web-applications, send

I want to be able to send an url of a page from a web app to a client in order to invite him to open the url.
I thought about using email (it is easy), or sms.. But I wonder if there are any ways of doing it.

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: Um...huh? Just other ways of sending him/her the URL? Off the top of my head: Email, SMS, Twitter, Facebook, Google+ hangout, telephone call, verbally in person, fax, passing a note in class, telegraph, miming, sending a letter by post, skywriting, interpretive dance...

Comment: Actually the client is supposed to be on the phone with the agent who wants to send him the url. The thing is that it is better if the client can easily click on the url to open the page. But I cannot use the social networks. I am not sure other solutions rather than email and sms exist but i'm hoping someone thought about it before.

Answer (score 0):

Email, SMS, and the fallback of reading it out to them is probably going to be all you can do.

Because of sometimes needing to read it out to them, you'll probably want to get a short domain you can put links on for your commonly-used ones, e.g.:

> Go to example dot com and click "How do I do X?" in the list

...where said link takes them where you wanted them to go.